# I get an error downloading javax.media.jai_core:1.1.3 from maven central

Tags: maven, playframework-2.0, geotools, jai, maven-central

I get an error downloading javax.media.jai_core:1.1.3 from maven central.

The error is:

```
download failed: javax.media#jai_core;1.1.3!jai_core.jar
```

using play compiler.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem at this moment is that maven-central doesn't have the .jar, which is a dependency from geotoolkit

[image: Sample of maven repo content]

If you need it, you could use the next public repositories:

https://maven.geotoolkit.org (jai-core is here)

https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/

Make sure geotoolkit-repo is before Maven Central, so that it resolves before Central which misses the jar.

Comment: I have tried both, but it is not working, it's trying to download a wrong url http://maven.geotoolkit.org/javax/media/jai/com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core/1.1.3/com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core-1.1.3.pom

Comment: "Make sure geotoolkit-repo is before Maven Central, so that it resolves before Central which misses the jar." Why??? When a jar isn't found in one repo, couldn't it simply look in the next one?
What if geotoolkit-repo misses a jar which is in Maven Central?

Answer (score 9):

For Gradle users:

```
    mavenCentral().content {
        excludeModule("javax.media", "jai_core")
    }
```

Comment: Note the underscore ;-)

Answer (score 6):

And move the http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools repo to the first position in your repo list. Otherwise it will probably still give you that error.

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Comment: It's necessary to have Geotools-repo first as Maven Central includes the dependency, but not the .jar. Therefore it is "resolved" in Central, but actually not found.

Central, pom but no jar: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/media/jai_core/1.1.3/
Geotools, pom and jar: https://repo.osgeo.org/#browse/browse:geotools-releases:javax%2Fmedia%2Fjai_core%2F1.1.3

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem, trying to add icepdf to my pom for a project. What worked for me was adding this exclusion inside de dependency tag:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Here is the link to the answer that helped me, hoping it helps some other people having this same issue:

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/48248739/10428307](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761727/basic-code-to-display-a-pdf-in-an-existing-jpanel)

Comment: If your project doesn't need jai-core it can work. What you should take into account that excluding a dependency from your project could result in some runtime errors depending of the functionality you are using.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for gradle with kotlin dsl (8.4)**

Below changes in file *build.gradle.kts*

Add jboss repository in repository section

```
 maven {
    url = uri("https://repository.jboss.org")
 }
```

Exclude from dependencies using jai_core

```
implementation("org.geotools:gt-shapefile:30.0") {
    exclude("javax.media", "jai_core")
}
implementation("org.geotools:gt-swing:30.0") {
    exclude("javax.media", "jai_core")
}
```

Add dependency on jai.core that exists in jboss maven repository

```
implementation("javax.media:jai-core:1.1.3")
```