# using #search parameter on a JWebBrowser grays out display field

Tags: java, swing, pdf, repaint

I´ve already searched for related posts on stack, but didn´t find quite the right answer;
Im using [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761727/basic-code-to-display-a-pdf-in-an-existing-jpanel) to display a .pdf file in my frame.

Now I want to use the `JWebBrowser.navigate()`+ `(filePath + "#search=anyString")` to search this .pdf file for the specific string.
Unfortunately I´m unable to reload the JWebBrowser afterwards. So the correct filepath is submitted (checked that in the pdf adress bar), but the JWebBrowser turns gray and nothing happens.

When using the `navigate()` to load another file and afterwards navigate to the old file again, it works just fine.

I tried `revalidate()`, `repaint()` and stuff like this but I cant get this to work.

Example:

```
btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                browser.navigate(filePath + "#search=flower");
                browser.revalidate();
                browser.repaint();
            }
        });
```

I appreciate any kind of advice!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meanwhile I've found a solution, although it might be not the perfect one:

You can just remove the JWebbrowser object from your current Frame/Panel and just add it again.
This way it will work just fine.

Just in case someone is having a related problem to this one.

Greetz